# Chrome auto scroll up and down infinitely at certain speed

Tags: loops, google-chrome, console, auto, autoscroll

I'm trying to have a tab in chrome auto scroll up and down infinitely at slow speed preferably. Can I set that up through Console? if yes, how?

Thank you in advance,
Shqipdon

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code:

```
intervalThing = setInterval( function(){
    window.scrollBy(0,1)
}, 25);
```

which seems to be working fine, and scrolls the page down however I need some sort of loop to run the lines of code below that will scroll the page up

```
intervalThing = setInterval( function(){
    window.scrollBy(0,-1)
}, 25);
```

...and this needs to run infinitely or until page is refreshed.

Any ideas?